Не могу подключиться к интернету в ubuntu
только поставил Ubuntu 24.04 LTS и не могу подключиться к интернету, пишет что "Кабель не подключен", хотя это не так, а wi-fi параметров вообще нет. Подскажите, что делать?
Решил посмотреть есть ли сетевой драйвер ввел "lspci | grub Ethernet"
выдал: 05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semicondutor ... (rev 05).
В этой же сети есть ноут с Linux Fedora, на нем сразу все работало (и работает) нормально.
Перезагружал комп, роутер, перевставлял кабел ethernet, но ничего не помогает.
PS. решил вместо убунту поставить федору и ничего не поменялось.

Вот так выглядит на ноуте.


ifconfig -a чё говорит?
